# Accidentally removed custom workflow from list

Tags: workflow

I've accidentally removed a custom workflow from list :(

I was doing a bulk data import and didnt want the workflow(s) firing against each item.

I've now come back in to turn the workflows back on but I cant figure out how or where!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't solve my issue, but I found a work around.

In SPD, I created a new blank workflow.

In the new workflow, I deleted the newly created aspx, xml, xmol, etc., files.

In my old workflow, I copied the exiting files, and pasted them into the new workflow.

I then opened the new workflow, verified my steps and content, then selected finished. 

This did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what "removing" means for you. If you really remove it via the Workflows in the List settings, than association is gone. This means you need to go again in Workflows and re-associate it. Then it depends on how it has been created: via SPD or custom code, or e.g. Nintex/K2, etc. - also depends whether it was a List workflow, Reusable (which means it could be Content-Type attached) or Site.

Try opening up your site via SPD and search for it starting with your list, site, on the left-navigation panel. If you're lucky, maybe you only removed association, which means that you could redo it, otherwise you might not be happy about deleting it.

If you simply forbid it to "new instance" (2nd option out of the 3) you re-instate it easily, again via List Settings - Workflows.